# Parsing Api Response Django Module

Tags: python, django

I am using this magic the gathering api in django. Instead of using requests to call the url I can use the built in functions. But the response is confusing me.

When I call

```
cards = Card.where(page=50).where(pageSize=500).all()
```

Then print out `cards`

I get data that looks like this in my terminal.

```
mtgsdk.card.Card object at 0x10696bcc0>, <mtgsdk.card.Card object at 0x10696bcf8>, <mtgsdk.card.Card object at 0x10696bd30>, <mtgsdk.card.Card object at 0x10696bd68>, <mtgsdk.card.Card object at 0x10696bda0>]
```

I was thinking I maybe need to decode it and it's a dict but I basically throwing darts blindly and have no clue if I am getting any closer.

Someone please shed some light here. What format is this response in and how would I handle it?

```
def graphs(request):
    data = []
    cards = Card.where(page=50).where(pageSize=500).all()
    mtg_data = str(cards)
    print(mtg_data)
    data.append(cards)
    return render(request, 'graphs/graphs.html', {'data': data})
```

Then I am trying to access the card in the template like this, but I get nothing.

```
<div class="frame" id="basic">
              <ul class="clearfix">
                {% for cards in data %}
        <li><a href="#"><img src="{{cards.image_url }}" /></a></li>
                {% endfor %}
              </ul>
            </div>
```

[API HERE](https://docs.magicthegathering.io)

[GITHUB](https://github.com/MagicTheGathering/mtg-sdk-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've appended the list of cards to an empty list, so now `data` is a list consisting of a single item, which is itself a list. Instead, you just want to send the cards list itself to the template.

```
return render(request, 'graphs/graphs.html', {'data': cards})
```

Comment: Thank you. I really try hard and never leave from my computer. I do not see why I cant just awaken and understand fully.